# Problems after using Primefaces filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a datatable where one of the columns is editable.
As long as i dont use my filter i can navigate through my list and can edit the entry in any row i want. I dont get any errors and my changes are persisted in the DB correctly.

But after i once used any of the filter everything goes sideways. The filter itself works properly.

But when i now try to edit any entry the event.oldValue() from my CellEditEvent is always null and i cant persist my entries.

And only the first page of my paginator is filled with data. Every other page is empty.

Here is the view:

```xhtml
<div class="Container100">
    <p:dataTable paginator="true" rows="15" var="listReportingParticipantOverview" value="#{reportingBean.listReportingParticipantOverview}" 
                 id="participantOverviewId" widgetVar="participantOverviewId"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell" editInitEvent="dblclick"
                 emptyMessage="#{msg['system.no_result']}"
                 filteredValue="#{reportingBean.filteredListReportingParticipantOverview}">
                                 
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{reportingBean.onCellEdit}" update=":reportingForm:msgs"/>
    
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['model.reporting.participant_overview.name']}" filterBy="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['model.reporting.participant_overview.dateOfBirth']}" filterBy="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.dateOfBirth}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.dateOfBirth}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="#{msg['model.reporting.participant_overview.email']}" filterBy="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.email}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.email}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{listReportingParticipantOverview.email}" style="width:100%" label="name"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</div>
```

Here is the bean:

```java
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "reportingBean2")
public class ReportingBean2 extends BeanController implements Serializable {

    List<ReportingParticipantOverview> listReportingParticipantOverview = new ArrayList<ReportingParticipantOverview>();
    List<ReportingParticipantOverview> filteredListReportingParticipantOverview;

    ContactRepository contactRepository;
    ContactRepository contactRepositoryOtherDBContext;
    CommunicationRepository communicationRepositoryOtherDBContext;

    private AbstractApplicationContext otherDBContext;

    public void initData() {
        this.listReportingParticipantOverview = this.contactRepositoryOtherDBContext
                .selectParticipantOverviewReporting();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        otherDBContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext_otherDB.xml");

        this.contactRepository = this.getApplicationContext().getBean(ContactRepository.class);
        this.contactRepositoryOtherDBContext = otherDBContext.getBean(ContactRepository.class);
        this.communicationRepositoryOtherDBContext = otherDBContext.getBean(CommunicationRepository.class);
    }

    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

//          ...
    }

    public List<ReportingParticipantOverview> getListReportingParticipantOverview() {
        return listReportingParticipantOverview;
    }

    public void setListReportingParticipantOverview(
            List<ReportingParticipantOverview> listReportingParticipantOverview) {
        this.listReportingParticipantOverview = listReportingParticipantOverview;
    }

    public List<ReportingParticipantOverview> getFilteredListReportingParticipantOverview() {
        return filteredListReportingParticipantOverview;
    }

    public void setFilteredListReportingParticipantOverview(
            List<ReportingParticipantOverview> filteredListReportingParticipantOverview) {
        this.filteredListReportingParticipantOverview = filteredListReportingParticipantOverview;
    }
}
}
```

I am using Java 8, Eclipse 2021-03 and Primefaces 10.0.0.
Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: I think its a bug in 10.0.0.  Can you try 11.0.0-RC1.  Lots of Datatable issues resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tested it and indeed it works now.I developed it according the showcase from the Primefaces website. But i wasnt aware that it was the showcase for 11.0.0-RC1. So i guess i need to remplement it according the older version.